# How to install older version of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-12.04

I'm installing Jenkins 1.532-1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04, and I need to install it using `apt-get` repo. I ran following three commands which installs latest Jenkins just fine:

- `wget  -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | apt-key add -`
- `echo "deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`
- `apt-get update`

But I need to install this specific version 1.532-1.1 (for a reason that is beyond my control). I tried `apt-get install jenkins=1.532-1.1`, this gives version not found error.

I've had a look at this link http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ but installing *.deb is not option for me.

Any idea how I can install jenkins 1.532-1.1 using apt-get?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get that version from the apt repository any more.  Why is installing from a local .deb file not an option ?

Comment: There's this pre-written enterprise application that runs apt-get command dynamically :(

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: And why wasnt it moved to askubuntu.com 3 years back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the version 1.532-1.1 that you mention, I'm guessing that you actually want use the LTS release repository (I can only see 1.532.1 though):
http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/

But gareht_bowles is right, it is not in the apt repository any more. You can check it via

```
apt-cache policy jenkins
```

You should proceed with the deb file.

Comment: I am using `Kubuntu 14.04` and i get error while I run `apt-get cache policy jenkins`. Is `apt-cache policy jenkins` correct?

Answer (score 8):

Install jenkins specific version without using this command `apt-get install jenkins`.

Solution: Run the following commands (e.g. 1.652 is the jenkins version that you need to install)

```
$ wget "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/binary/jenkins_1.652_all.deb"  
$ dpkg -i jenkins_1.652_all.deb
```

**During the installation dpkg fails with the following error:**

```
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
```

Soultion: **This will install the dependencies**

```
$ apt-get -y install -f
```

Package download location :
http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/

Comment: Had to `sudo apt-get purge jenkins` and install again after the `apt-get` fix. Otherwise had the "unit jenkins.service not found".